# How to get pronunciation spoken automatically when googling word's definition?

Tags: google-search, audio

When a word definition is shown clicking the speaker icon will speak its pronunciation:

[image]

How to make it automatic on page load?

Comment: If you are using Firefox I can write you a script to do this.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have already made a script below. Can you check if there's a better way to do this? In my use, the pronunciations are only spoken after the page loading is finished, which is a little slow in my laptop. If there is a way to pronounce it right when the sound is downloaded, then I don't have to wait for the sound before closing the tab.

Comment: That's what i've been trying to do but my script is failing when it comes in contact with Google instant, something about the way Google displays results

Comment: The definition can be shown when you are still typing the word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the icon, choose `Inspect Element`. On the correct element, right click and choose `Copy` > `CSS Selector`. Then create a userscript with this line

```
document.querySelector("INSERT SELECTOR").click();
```

## [Userscript on Greasyfork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/29771-google-auto-speak-pronunciation)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Google auto-speak pronunciation 
// @namespace   https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/29771-google-pronunciation-speak
// @include     https://*google.com*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @description Auto speak pronunciation when googling word's definitions 
// @author      Ooker
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelector(".lr_dct_spkr > input:nth-child(1)").click();
```